# Return pointer to reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

When I return the pointer to the reference type in a function, I got a compiler error `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`. The function is like this

```
Testing& copy(Testing test)
{
    x = test.x;
    return this;
}
```

But when I change the `this` to `*this`, the error is gone.

Comment: References can't have pointers, but pointers *can* have references. If you want to return a pointer to your object, return `this`. If you want to return a reference to your object, return `*this`.

Comment: What is your question ? `this` is pointer, `*this` is a reference, and your function compile if you return a reference. There's no question.

Comment: @WhozCraig could you elaborate, I absoluletly do not see what you try to mean.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I mean you can have reference to a pointer (such as an out-param pointer passed by reference `(int *& int_ptr_ref)`, but you cannot have a pointer to a reference (this is not allowed: `int&* var;`). A pointer to a reference would be nothing more than a pointer to the *referenced* object, which is nothing more than taking the address of the object (through a reference or otherwise) Such as as `int a; int& b=a, int* c = &b;` the address in `c` is `&a`;

Comment: @WhozCraig Okay. Not sure it was directly helping the OP though :-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland it was more a direct response to the title of the question, and what he *appears* to want to do, but clearly not what he *should* do.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh sorry I didn't notice that in the title... well done :-) Thx for pointing it out. +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the `this` special variable holds a **pointer** to the class instance.

You're creating a function that returns a **reference** to an instance, another name to the same memory position.

When you use `*this` you're dereferencing the `this` pointer, getting to the real memory position holding the current instance and returning an alias to that.

It does work! Just beware of the [Object Slicing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) in case you need Polymorphism.

Comment: Slicing only applies when returning/assigning by value.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers and references are not the same thing. `this` is a *pointer* to the current class instance, while `*this` is the actual instance as a value (to be more specific, an lvalue, when used as a return value).